# Can't move my spawned player prefab before some changes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This problem happens with Networking.

Before this problem I used `Auto Create
Player`.

`MainCamera` showed all map, when player connects - script turned `MainCamera` off, and `PlayerCamera` turned on. And also I could control my player.

Now, I want to spawn my player by pressing button. I disabled auto create player. And then used this script to spawn my player:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class MenuChoose : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public Transform spawn1;
    public GameObject tank3;
    public bool tank3spawned = false;
    public bool color3;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!tank3spawned)
        {
            if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Alpha3)) || color3)
            {
                var tank3go = Instantiate(tank3, spawn1.position, spawn1.rotation);
                NetworkServer.Spawn(tank3go);
                tank3spawned = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But my `MainCamera` doesn't turn off. Also, I can't move my tank. Btw, here is my script that disabled `MainCamera` before changes:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class PlayerSetup : NetworkBehaviour
{
    private Camera sceneCamera;

    [SerializeField]
    Behaviour[] componentsToDisable; // disable some scripts for multiplayer

    void Start()
    {
        if (!isLocalPlayer)
            for (int i = 0; i < componentsToDisable.Length; i++)
                componentsToDisable[i].enabled = false;
            else
        {
            sceneCamera = Camera.main;
            if (sceneCamera != null)
                sceneCamera.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        if (sceneCamera != null)
            sceneCamera.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You say `here is my script that disabled MainCamera before changes` .. why aren't you using it anymore to disable the MainCamera?

Comment: @derHugo I didn't delete it, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is that [`Camera.main`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html) might not return the actual `MainCamera` you want to get there but instead might return your Player camera

> This property uses `FindGameObjectsWithTag` internally

so if you tagged the Camera on the Player object (prefab) also as `MainCamera` it might simply find the wrong object.

---

What you could try instead would be to have a global `MainCameraProvider` that stores the reference right from the start using a Singleton-Pattern

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
public class MainCameraProvider : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Camera MainCamera;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // check if already set by another instance
        if(MainCamera)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("MainCamera is already set!");
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        MainCamera = GetComponent<Camera>();
    }
}
```

having this component attached to the `MainCamera` object you could than reliable disable it using in your player script attached to the `tank3` prefab:

```
public class PlayerSetup : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    Behaviour[] componentsToDisable; // disable some scripts for multiplayer

    void Start()
    {
        if (!isLocalPlayer)
        {
            foreach(var component in componentsToDisable)
            {
                component.enabled = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MainCameraProvider.MainCamera.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        MainCameraProvider.MainCamera.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, but why can't I control, move my prefab?

Comment: I don't know ... what does that have to do with the code you and I provided? Might have to do something with the `componentsToDisable` ...?